# Why can't I change the tag on my UIButton?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a NSString like "s21" and am trying to convert the numbers to a button's tag.

I am doing:

```
NSString *temp = [[array objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"s" withString:@""];
[_b0 setTag: [temp intValue]];
```

_b0 is my UIButton.

I am running an NSLog to check the tag after I run setTag, but the button's tag doesn't change and remains to be 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Log the value of `temp` and check that it's correct.

Comment: do NSLog on `temp` and see what it has and also on `_b0` to ensure it is not `nil`. also `NSLog(@"%d",_b0.tag)` after setting tag. Let us know.

Comment: temp is showing 21 and _b0 is showing 0 before and after setting the tag.

Comment: I checked your code it's working for me. Try to nslog [array objectAtIndex:0] and make sure your button is initialized.

Comment: _b0 showing 0 means that it is nil, is it an outlet from the storyboard or a programmatically added button? If it is the latter you should either initialise it in viewDidLoad or lazy initialise it in the getter method.

Comment: Figured it out. I reseted my nib earlier today and forgot to re-associate the button with _b0. Thanks for the help guys. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: check IBOutlet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `IBOutlet` connection of your `UIButton` if you are creating it through nib file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct there is no problem because i've implemented at my end. See below i think you are doing something wrong in other code..

```
NSString *temp = [[array objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"s" withString:@""];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:btn];
[btn setTag: [temp intValue]];

NSLog(@"Tag %d",btn.tag);
```

Output :

**Tag 21**

Comment: Something else was definitely wrong. My fault. Sorry for wasting everyones time. I reseted my nib earlier today and forgot to re-associate the button with _b0. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"S21";
NSString *newStr = [str substringFromIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
NSString *temp = [[array objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"s" withString:@""];
_b0.tag = [temp intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*temp = [[array objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"s" withString:@""];
_b0.tag = [temp intValue];
```